# <PRE> TAG doesn't work?

Tags: html, pre

Here, what I am doing is printing my javascript code by wrapping between "pre" tags like this :

```
<pre>
    var sum = function(toSum) {
    var j = 0;
    for(var i=0; i<toSum.length; i++) {
        j = j + toSum[i];   
    }

    console.log("The sum of array is " + j);
};

sum([1,2,3,4]);

var multiply = function(toMultiply) {
    var j = 1;
    for(var i=0; i<toMultiply.length; i++) {
        j = j * toMultiply[i];  
    }

    console.log("The multiplication of array is " + j);
};

multiply([1,2,3,4]);
</pre>
```

But what I am actual getting is this :

```
var sum = function(toSum) {
var j = 0;
for(var i=0; i
```

Why is that so? How can I get "**pre**" tag working?

Comment: You need to replace the `<` with `&lt;` inside your JavaScript code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `&lt;` instead of `<`.
Similarly, use `&gt;` for `>` and `&amp;` for `&` when displaying in HTML.

Your for loop will be like:

```
for(var i=0; i&lt;toSum.length; i++) {
...
}
```